# how to log in with a google account on a website

Tags: javascript, html, css, sign, google-authentication

how do you implement a sign in with google button on your website? iv been trying to find the answer to my problem and i can never get the right answer. So what im asking is that, you have a google sign in button. which rdirects you to their sign in page. The user signs in and then have my website say that there signed in with their google acount.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look on [Google's Authentication API](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2). You can find all the documentation you will require for this on the that link.

Enjoy :)